# jQuery wordpress customizer with layers theme open widget on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I use a wordpress theme called layers, it has it's own layout builder that uses custom widgets to add content to a page.

I am trying to develop a user onboarding plugin for this when a user enters the customizer for the first time. What I am trying to ahieve is when a user clicks "Next" on step 4 (the button has the class `.step4`), the layers widget opens in the customizer.

I can see that within layers there is a function called `layers_expand_widget` which I am trying to bind to a on click event.

Here is the contents of the layers_expand_widget function:

```
function layers_expand_widget( $widget_li, $widget, e ){

    // Instant user feedback
    $widget_li.addClass('layers-focussed');

    // Instantly remove other classes
    $('.layers-focussed').not( $widget_li ).removeClass('layers-focussed layers-loading');

    // Handle the first time Init of a widget.
    if ( !$widget_li.hasClass( 'layers-loading' ) && !$widget_li.hasClass( 'layers-initialized' ) ){

        $widget_li.addClass('layers-loading');
        $widget_li.addClass( 'layers-initialized' );

        if ( 'click' === e.type ) {
            // If event is 'click' it's our early invoked event so we can do things before all the WP things
            setTimeout(function(){
                $widget.trigger( 'layers-interface-init' );
            }, 50 );
        } else {
            // If event is 'expand' it's a WP invoked event that we use as backup if the 'click' was not used.
            // eg 'shift-click' on widget in customizer-preview
            $widget.trigger( 'layers-interface-init' );
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my script (which is loaded after the above code).

```
jQuery('.step4').on('click', function (e) {
    var $widget_li = $('#customize-control-widget_layers-widget-column-30');
    var $widget = $widget_li.find( '.widget' );
    layers_expand_widget( $widget_li, $widget, e );
});
```

Currently my script does nothing, is there something obvious I am missing?

**UPDATE: Here is my full js code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('body').attr('onboarding_step', 'step1');
  $('body.wp-customizer').addClass('skizzar_onboarding');
  $('<div class="so_overlay"></div>').insertBefore('body.wp-customizer');

  $('.so_overlay').html('<div id="onboarding_steps_container" class="step1"></div>');
  $('#onboarding_steps_container').html('<div class="onboarding_steps"></div><div class="button_holder"><button id="next">NEXT</button><button id="prev">PREVIOUS</button></div>');

// here's the steps
 var steps = [
   "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step1.php",
   "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step2.php",
   "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step3.php",
   "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step4.php",
   "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step5.php",
 ];
 var classes = [
   "step1",
   "step2",
   "step3",
   "step4",
   "step5",
 ]
 counter = 0;
 $('.onboarding_steps').load(steps[counter]);
 $('#next').click(function () {
   counter = (counter + 1) % steps.length; 
   $('.onboarding_steps').load(steps[counter]); 
   $('#onboarding_steps_container, .button_holder button').attr('class', 'step' + (counter + 1)); 
   $('body').attr('onboarding_step', 'step' + (counter + 1)); 
 });

  $( 'button #next.step2' ).on("click", function(){
    alert('im here');
  });

});
```

Comment: Have you verified that you are actually getting into the click handler function as well as layers_expand_widget?

Comment: @mhodges i'm not too sure how I would do that. If it helps, here is the full code that contains the layers_expand_widget function. Also, if I add console.log('Button pressed'); into my code, nothing shows in the console whilst layers_expand_widget is present

Comment: just put alert("i'm here"); in the click handler as well as at the top of your layers_expand_widget() function. If you get an alert, you know that you have entered the code block. If not, you can eliminate many errors and focus on why the function is not executing (wrong selector, wrong syntax, etc.)

Comment: One thing I noticed too is that in your .removeClass() you are removing 2 classes at once. I have found that to be problematic at times. Chain those together: .removeClass("layers-focused").removeClass("layers-loading");

You can also remove the .not(..) if you switch the line that adds the class and the line that removes the classes. Let me know if any of those things help

Comment: Also, you are not removing the layers-loading class on $widget_li if that makes a difference. If it's ever applied to $widget_li, none of the rest of the code in your layers_expand_widget() function will run because the !$widget_li.hasClass("layers-loading") will return false

Comment: Thanks for your comments @mhodges - actually the theme doesn't belong to me, so I'll probably leave those edits alone as they will be oveidden on upgrade. I can't seem to get the alert to work, no matter what selector I use which is very frustrating. Just in case it helps, i've added my whole js code to my question

Comment: Thanks for adding the js. Could you also post the relevant HTML so I can see how your DOM is laid out? That way we can get the selectors targeting the right elements